# Random Odd Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

My professor gave us our first assignment (Cs315), which involves dealing with some huge (odd) integers and determining if they are prime. I started to do this in c++ until I realized that even long long ints could not hold the numbers needed, so I was left with the choices of making a class of vectors in c++, or learning python in a few days. This simple piece of Python code is supposed to spit out an odd 256 bit random number. It spits out random numbers, both even and odd, and I don't know why, but my guess is a that it is a simple syntactical error that I am not seeing.

```
import random
x = random.getrandbits(256)
if x % 2 == 0:
    x +  1
print x
```

Comment: `x + 1` -> `x = x + 1`

Comment: `x + 1` does not assign `x + 1` back to `x`.

Comment: do `x+=1` or `x = x+1`

Comment: Augmented assignment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `x + 1` back to `x`. You can either do this like this: `x = x+1` or like this: `x += 1`

Comment: I feel like an idiot. It is the same thing in c++. After 3 years of programming, you think that something that silly would have been spotted. That's what I get for working in a foreign language.

Comment: @somgoozy haha don't worry about it, everyone makes these kinds of mistakes :)

Comment: Many bugs in software are caused by silly mistakes like this, don't worry about it